# Get frequency counts for a for a float column within range -1 to +1 by 0.1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with index datetime (spanning over multiple days) that has a column "score" which contains floats in the range -1 to +1

```
I want to get a frequency of "score" in breaks of 0.1 for each day as a df
expected output:
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| date       | -1  | ... | 1   |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2020-10-03 | x   | ... | y   |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ...        | ... | ... | ... |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2020-11-20 | z   | ... | a   |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I have included json of 30 values below from one days data:

```
my_json_data = {"score":{"1601680608000":0.796,"1601680613000":0.631,"1601680899000":-0.7645,"1601681020000":-0.9078,"1601681066000":-0.296,"1601681112000":0.2579,"1601681240000":-0.4199,"1601681379000":0.5574,"1601681562000":-0.4588,"1601681595000":0.5574,"1601681618000":0.0,"1601681757000":0.0,"1601681777000":0.6588,"1601681903000":0.3291,"1601681915000":-0.1027,"1601682034000":0.644,"1601682104000":-0.4854,"1601682116000":0.6369,"1601682312000":-0.363,"1601682464000":0.3687,"1601682529000":-0.34,"1601682549000":0.0,"1601682598000":-0.5867,"1601682610000":-0.5046,"1601682869000":0.1531,"1601682877000":0.0,"1601682912000":0.6199,"1601682938000":-0.5262,"1601683061000":0.824,"1601683110000":0.0},"date":{"1601680608000":1601680608000,"1601680613000":1601680613000,"1601680899000":1601680899000,"1601681020000":1601681020000,"1601681066000":1601681066000,"1601681112000":1601681112000,"1601681240000":1601681240000,"1601681379000":1601681379000,"1601681562000":1601681562000,"1601681595000":1601681595000,"1601681618000":1601681618000,"1601681757000":1601681757000,"1601681777000":1601681777000,"1601681903000":1601681903000,"1601681915000":1601681915000,"1601682034000":1601682034000,"1601682104000":1601682104000,"1601682116000":1601682116000,"1601682312000":1601682312000,"1601682464000":1601682464000,"1601682529000":1601682529000,"1601682549000":1601682549000,"1601682598000":1601682598000,"1601682610000":1601682610000,"1601682869000":1601682869000,"1601682877000":1601682877000,"1601682912000":1601682912000,"1601682938000":1601682938000,"1601683061000":1601683061000,"1601683110000":1601683110000}}
```

I am new to pandas/python so I appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: what do you mean by "frequency counts" exactly?  Counts, fractional counts, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import json
data = json.dumps(my_json_data)
df = pd.read_json(data)

counts = pd.cut(df.score, np.round(np.arange(-1,1.1,0.1),2))    
counts.value_counts().sort_index()
```

output:

```
(-1.0, -0.9]    1
(-0.9, -0.8]    0
(-0.8, -0.7]    1
(-0.7, -0.6]    0
(-0.6, -0.5]    3
(-0.5, -0.4]    3
(-0.4, -0.3]    2
(-0.3, -0.2]    1
(-0.2, -0.1]    1
(-0.1, -0.0]    5
(-0.0, 0.1]     0
(0.1, 0.2]      1
(0.2, 0.3]      1
(0.3, 0.4]      2
(0.4, 0.5]      0
(0.5, 0.6]      2
(0.6, 0.7]      5
(0.7, 0.8]      1
(0.8, 0.9]      1
(0.9, 1.0]      0
Name: counts, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value_counts` with the `bins` parameter:

```
df['score'].value_counts(bins=np.linspace(-1.,1.,21), sort=False)
```

Output:

```
(-1.001, -0.9]    1
(-0.9, -0.8]      0
(-0.8, -0.7]      1
(-0.7, -0.6]      0
(-0.6, -0.5]      3
(-0.5, -0.4]      3
(-0.4, -0.3]      2
(-0.3, -0.2]      1
(-0.2, -0.1]      1
(-0.1, 0.0]       5
(0.0, 0.1]        0
(0.1, 0.2]        1
(0.2, 0.3]        1
(0.3, 0.4]        2
(0.4, 0.5]        0
(0.5, 0.6]        2
(0.6, 0.7]        5
(0.7, 0.8]        1
(0.8, 0.9]        1
(0.9, 1.0]        0
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Histogram plot:

```
df['score'].hist(bins=np.linspace(-1.,1.,21))
```

[image]

Comment: oooh, didn't know about `bins` :)